# Setting up Joomla 2.5 logs

Tags: logging, joomla2.5

I have tried to configure Joomla 2.5 logs by specifying the path to the log folder in configuration.php. I have this Joomla site that I have not been able to login to the admin panel for a while now. Each time I try to login, I get "500 -an error has occurred". I configured the logs to see whether I could know why this is happening but the logs don't show me anything.

Please how can I know the cause of this error? Without being able to login to the admin side, how can I know where exactly it is coming from.

NB: the url is 65.98.61.98/~nnigeria/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so the problem was that the password was reset by some mysterious means. I reset it and I am good to go. Thanks for the help anyway @Arunu

Answer (score 1):

I checked the backend of ur site. Try solutions described in these links.
http://www.joomlart.com/forums/showthread.php?77240-500-An-error-has-occurred.
http://bikramkawan.com.np/solved-joomla-1-7-500-an-error-has-occurred-return-to-control-panel/